# Initialize all lazy loaded collections in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

**I have tried most of the solutions for this issue I am facing, but I am still not clear.**

I am using Hibernate 4.

I have parent-child relationships in my entity. By default, I have used lazy loading for all the collections in my parent entity. However, in some cases, I need to load the whole object graph. In such cases, I want to force hibernate to load all the collections. I know that by using `criteria.setFetchMode("collectionName",FetchMode.JOIN)`, I can load a specific collection. However, if I tried to do that for multiple collections, I am getting `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`.

Here is my code:

**Entity**

Ignoring a few fields and getter and setter methods

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "EmployeeId")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EmployeeId")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    private List<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddresses;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EmployeeId")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    private List<EmployeeLanguage> employeeLanguages;

}
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
public HibernateUtil{

    public TEntity findById(Class<TEntity> clazz, long id) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",id));
            ClassMetadata metadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(clazz);

            String[] propertyNamesArray = metadata.getPropertyNames();
            for(int i=0;i<propertyNamesArray.length;i++){
                criteria.setFetchMode(propertyNamesArray[i], FetchMode.JOIN);
            }
            return (TEntity)criteria.uniqueResult();
        }
}
```

**Service**

```
private void getAllEmployee(Employee employee) {
         //invoke the findAll method of hibernateutil
}
```

I want to have eager-loading of all the collections of Employee in findAll() method. 
Please tell me how to get that done.

**Adding the stacktrace when using FetchType.SELECT inside the HIbernateUtil**

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.myapp.hr.entity.Employee.employeeAddresses, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
    java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1099)
    java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1098)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:90)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:186)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1819)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:253)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:439)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:178)
```

Comment: Can you not simply change the fetch mode to eager, rather than lazy?

Comment: No.  I need it to be lazy except in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

I mentioned this in a comment in my other answer but it's different enough and I don't want to lose Gimby's insights by editing my original answer.

You can use reflection to lookup the fields with the `@LazyCollection` annotation and call `Hibernate.initialize()` on them. It would look something like this:

```
    public static <T> void forceLoadLazyCollections(Class<T> tClass, T entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (Field field : tClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            LazyCollection annotation = field.getAnnotation(LazyCollection.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                try {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Hibernate.initialize(field.get(entity));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    log.warning("Unable to force initialize field: " + field.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your fetch mode to `FetchMode.SELECT`. Using a join to pull in a collection can only be applied to one collection/table because it causes lots of duplicate data to be pulled across the wire. Using separate selects to pull in collections can be used as much as you want.

Comment: If I use FetchMode.Select, I am getting LazyInitializationException. It is not forcing to load the lazy loaded collections :(

Comment: Would it be acceptable to call `Hibernate.initialize()` for each collection on the entity that you retrieved?

Comment: But, I do not get the reference to each collections inside the HibernateUtil class right? I need to do that inside the service, which will result in lot of duplicate code (in all the services)

Comment: You could use reflection to get the getters that return collections or to look for fields that have the `@LazyCollection` annotation. Honestly, I'm a little surprised you're getting a LazyInitializationException. Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: Added the stacktrace to the question

Comment: Why is it so surprising? The javadoc of FetchMode clearly states: "Represents an association fetching strategy. This is used together with the Criteria API to specify runtime fetching strategies." So it only affects the criteria API apparently. It would be pretty contradictory to tell Hibernate "Yeah use LAZY fetching... but still fetch them EAGERly!" Lazy does not really imply how the data is fetched, it implies WHEN the data is fetched: lazy = as late as possible.

Comment: @Gimby Good clarification. It seems the asker doesn't have much choice other than to explicitly fetch the collections **after** retrieving the parent entity. Either with `Hibernate.initialize()` or accessing each collection in a way that triggers the lazy fetch while the session is still available.

Comment: Actually I go as far as: you don't want this to be an automated mapping in this case, this needs to be a DAO method which fetches the relevant data at the appropriate time.

Comment: You should write your thoughts as an answer. They sound pretty solid to me.

Comment: @Gimby The problem I am facing is that, there are more than 10 collections in some of my entities. When I need to load the whole object together, I have to do `Hibernate.initialize("collection1")` for each of the collections. I want to avoid doing this in each of the DAO layer, and instead expose a generic method to EAGER load the whole entity. Is this not a proper way?